# Jquery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` which contains a QuickTime movie. It displays in a dialog. When the user clicks a link, this div will display in the dialog, `$("div").dialog()`. It is working fine in FireFox and also works in IE, but in IE it shows the div on the page first and then shows in the dialog box.

I used `display: none` on the div on the page.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal behavior of Jquery UI dialog, because dialog box is **div** on your page. So, calling `dialog()` method in `document.ready()` function makes to wait all content to load and after that only shows dialog.

So, making your dialog div's style `display:none` is dialog's normal usage.